# How to fill fields in web view in android with java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I am trying to fill some fields in my android web view. but all the time I have this error `01-28 05:06:22.980: E/Web Console(2827): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at null:1`

I have searched but didnt find some solution. How can I resolve this?
Here is my code

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        String url = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

               public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                   webView.loadUrl("javascript: {"
                            + "document.getElementById('AddSerialNum').value = '"
                            + ABC
                            + "';"
                            + "document.getElementById('ctl00_PageContent_lblName').value = '"
                            + ABC + "';};");

                }
            });
    }
```

this is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <body>

 <div style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #dfdfdf 3px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 10px; HEIGHT: 25px;">
               ......          
                <div style="padding: 10px;">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="float: left;">
                                    <div>

                                    <form>Serial Number: <input type="text" name="AddSerialNum"></form><br><br>

                                        <span id="ctl00_PageContent_lblName" style="font-weight:bold;"></span>
                                    </div>......
```

Is there any way to fill the fields and get data later with java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `getElementById` you will get an DOM Element by `id`. The id `AddSerialNum` does not exist, this is what the error tells you.
You have an `input` with `name="AddSerialNum"`, which, i think you want to get. Either add an `id` to it, or use `getElementsByName("AddSerialNum")[0]`

**EDIT**:
Like i already pointed out, you have to use this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementsByName(\"AddSerialNum\")[0].value ='" + ABC + "';};");
```

The `getElementsByName` returns an array of elements, you have to get the first one with `[0]`

Comment: I have tried this `webView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementsByName(\"AddSerialNum\").value ='" + ABC + "';};");`
but my field is still empty

Comment: hey . can you please refer to any full example. I have not worked with this kind of code before .

Comment: @bbuecherl please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644551/auto-fill-forms-in-webview-by-javascript-android . it needs your help .

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a little bit more of code as sample.

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            private void setUserEmail(WebView view) {
                String js = "javascript: {document.getElementsByName(\"recover-email\")[0].value ='" + mEmail + "';};";
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                    view.evaluateJavascript(js, s -> {
                    });
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(js);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                mLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setUserEmail(view);
            }
    }
```